# Откуда пришел пользователь, ссылка с Ютуб

Tags: php, youtube

при попытки собрать статистику откуда пришел пользователь на сайт с помощью $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ютуб не отдает полной ссылки  на наш сайт к примеру вместо  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IoaDfCyGgJY&t  отдает просто https://www.youtube.com
может кто сталкивался как получить полную ссылку от перехода ?

Comment: Уже давно HTTP_REFERER не является "точной наукой", значение может быть пустой или оличаться от реального, так что забейте, ищите другие методы аналитики ))

Comment: – Arsen а какая сейчас есть альтернатива более удачного решения , без скриптов  аналитики я имею ввиду ?

Comment: а  ссылки  на ваш ресурс,по которым приходят пользователи, вы сами ставите?

Comment: если да, то можете к ссылкам для каждого отдельного ресурса, добавлять какой то параметр(GET) и следить

Comment: – Arsen нет немного не то ссылки устанавливают партнеры и прописывать гет параметры будет сложно